# How to Unit Test Against Remote Resources

Tags: unit-testing

I've been trying to learn how to properly unittest and set up unit tests for all of my code on a new project. The project I'm currently doing this for requires me running a lot of actions against Google BigQuery (i.e. create tables, insert, query, delete). I'm feeling like I can't truly test all of this functionality by mocking BigQuery because the actions I do against it are complicated and interdependent, and if there's a break in the middle somewhere, I want to catch it. Is it generally frowned upon to have something like an environment variable that specifies a test account built into my unit tests so they actually run against the remote service? This feels like the best way to truly test everything and hit tests that I couldn't hit with a mock. So, is this something people do? Are there some major downsides to doing things this way?

Comment: Can you clarify why you are hesitant to mock the role of BigQuery in your system? You mentioned that the actions you "do against it are complicated and interdependent." This is exactly why you should try to create unit tests, as opposed to integration tests; it can help you break these actions down into more manageable (and more maintainable) pieces.

Comment: @Lilshieste a typical request is composed of many objects built on top of each other. So, I can either mock all of these (and worry about having mocked something wrong), or I can just run against the actual server and know for certain whether or not something runs. The latter seems much safer, easier, and less time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to have a mix of unit and integration tests in my project. I believe both are equally valuable, but one thing to keep in mind when doing integration testing is to ensure that the tests are stable and repeatable.
There are several approaches, but I favor the approach of making the tests self sufficient by ensuring that all data dependencies are built in the test itself. This is important since you avoid failing tests due to failed assumptions about existing data in your data source.

A variation on this is to have a scaffolding script populate your data source with fixed test data. I find this to be less manageable since it can introduce dependencies between tests and changing the test data for one test may cause failure in another.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do is technically called integration tests but I do see your point.  I myself am doing both as well currently.  My interaction in my integration tests is with a database.  I find that these integration tests often catch way more errors than true unit tests and are generally more beneficial.  I will say however that unit tests are important as well.

I have found that integration tests can tend to take a much longer time since it's doing all this interaction and if this is a part of your nightly build process for example this can greatly increase the amount of time it takes for a build to complete.  Some of our builds take close to an hour at this point to complete which is sometimes a problem for us.

I will say when you introduce things like environment variables into the mix you have to start making sure that every developer on the team has this environment variable if they want to run the tests.  As a general rule of thumb I try to make it as simple as possible for everyone to build and run tests directly out of source control.  There is nothing more frustrating than not being able to build source code or execute unit tests directly out of source control.

Comment: Agree completely on the last paragraph. Problem is checking in any private keys to source control seems like a bigger problem, so I'm not sure how to facilitate these tests outside of using an environment variable or something of the sort (obviously with good documentation and clean errors with lots of explanation if someone has the variable set wrong). If there are other approaches here, I'd love to hear them. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful to think of things like BigQuery as just implementation details; means to an end.

Something in your application currently says "I need `x` - I'll use BigQuery to get it." Instead of having explicit knowledge of BigQuery, this thing could instead have knowledge of "some entity capable of getting `x`". This is the location of a [seam](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417&seqNum=2), and is where mocking would take place.

You mentioned that you don't want to mock all of the objects involved in creating a BigQuery request. *You are absolutely right in avoiding this.* That doesn't mean that you can't mock out BigQuery, though; you just need to [move up a rung](http://worrydream.com/LadderOfAbstraction/).